# Passing values from jinternalframe1 to jinternalframe2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I've been reading a lot about constructors in Java as well as searching here in stackoverflow for related questions but I'm still confused on how my program will get a string value from my jinternalframe1 to jinternalframe2.

I have a jinternalframe which calls jinternalframe1. Here's my code.

```
ForgotPassword fp = new ForgotPassword();
        JDesktopPane MainDesk = this.getDesktopPane();
        MainDesk.add(fp);
        this.dispose();
        fp.show();
```

And here's my jinternalframe1..

```
public class ForgotPassword extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public ForgotPassword(String acType, String uName) {
        initComponents();
        acType = AccountType.getSelectedItem() + "";
        uName = username.getText();

    }
```

AccountType variable is a jcombobox with three options: Administrator, LevelOne, LevelTwo.
username variable is a jTextField. I also have a jbutton called Next which calls jinternalframe2.

User will need to click Next button, and will check if username exist in the database. (I have already figured out this part) And then hides jinternalframe1 and calls jinternalframe2 if username exists in the database.

Now I am confused with this part.. jinternalframe2. I would like the Account Type and username value from jinternalframe1 to jinternalframe2.. I am trying this out but got no luck..

```
public class ForgotPassword2 extends ForgotPassword {

    public ForgotPassword2(String acType, String uName) {
        initComponents(); 

        AccountType.getText() = acType;
        username.getText() = uName;
    }
```

You'll notice that the variable AccountType here in jinternalframe2 is a jTextField.
Both AccountType and username jTextField here in jinternalframe2 is not editable (disabled).

Error occurs on this lines:

```
ForgotPassword fp = new ForgotPassword();


public ForgotPassword2(String acType, String uName)
```

Error message on both lines

> constructor ForgotPassword in class ForgotPassword cannot be applied
>   to given types;   required: String,String   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Can someone enlighten me on how to use constructors right on my program? I am using netbeans by the way. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little to do with constructors and more to do with passing information between objects of different classes. For one you don't mis-use of inheritance for this purpose as you appear to be doing. Instead you use composition -- the class that needs information from another class needs a valid reference to the active object of the other class. Then the first class can call methods on the other one.

I think that for your purposes, you will likely be better off getting the user's information in a modal fashion using an internal option pane such as a `JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(...)`. Whenever you open a modal dialog, the calling code halts at the point where you display the modal dialog. The calling code will then resume once the modal dialog is no longer visible, and at that point you can query the JPanel class that is displayed in your option pane for the data that it holds.

Note as an aside: if you are asking question about code, and you state that your code has an "error", you will want to post the full error message for all to see.

Also, this isn't valid Java:

```
AccountType.getText() = acType;
```

as you can't have a method call on the left side of an assignment statement.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the error messages. i'll edit my post.

Comment: @ashlrem: my point is still valid: 1) you are misusing inheritance. 2) use a JOptionPane that holds a JPanel.

Comment: thanks. just to make sure i got you correctly, instead of using jinternalframes, i should use JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(...) right?

i am actually new to java. i am reading about JOptionPane on this site: http://foodocs.com/projects/openjdk/versions/7/java_methods/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,int) that i have found on google. can i have a jtextfield inside a JOptionPane? If yes, how? Sorry I am kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: @ashlrem: you can have whatever component you'd like in a JOptionPane. Myself, I avoid using JInternalFrames as I don't find them too pleasing or useful. Most of my changes of view are done using CardLayout. All my modal information is obtained using modal JDialogs or JOptionPanes.

Comment: I'm testing out your suggestion to use JOptionPane instead of JInternalFrame. Getting some errors but I'll try to figure it out from here. Thank you very much!

Comment: I actually need some kind of help. I don't know if it is appropriate however, I just wanted to ask if you can show me a sample code using JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(...) related to my program?

First window have a jcombobox and a jtextfield and a Next jbutton.
User will choose something in jcombobox and types something in jtextfield then clicks next. Second window will open with two jtextfields which contains the string data of the jcombobox and jtextfield of the first window.

Or maybe atleast a link where I can start learning on how to code it. Thank you!

Comment: and i was able to figure it out @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. weird. big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What error occurs on those lines?
This is not a valid statement:

```
public ForgotPassword2(String acType, String uName)
```

It's not very clear what is your intended designe, but from what you posted I guess you need to create a new instance of ForgotPassword2:

```
public class ForgotPassword extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    String acType;
    String uName;


    public ForgotPassword(String acType, String uName) {
        this.acType = acType;
        this.uName = uName;
    }

    public void next(){
        ...
        ForgotPassword2 fp2 = new ForgotPassword2(this.acType, this.uName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Also this statement is very suspicious:

```
AccountType.getText() = acType;
```

This statement doesn't replace the reference to the String in the AccountType. You will need to call a setter.

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the error message. i have included it on my post above.

Comment: I am trying your suggestion as well, however, I am getting an error on line
`ForgotPassword fp = new ForgotPassword();`
when I tried to add variables on
`public ForgotPassword(String acType, String uName)`

here's the error message:
`constructor ForgotPassword in class ForgotPassword cannot be applied to given types; required: String,String found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: You cannot do this ```new ForgotPassword();``` if the only constructor you provide has two arguments.